# Pygame: how to blit an image that follows another image

Tags: python

I'm trying reproduce the game "Snake" in pygame, using the pygame.blit function, instead of pygame.draw. My question is how to make an image follow another image. I mean, make the snake's body photo follow your head. In the current state of my program the head moves on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep positions of snake segments on list (first segment is head).

Later new position of head insert before first segment (and remove last segment).

Use this list to blit snake segments.